# RStudio: define path to R on startup automatically

Tags: r, rstudio

I have installed multiple versions of R which are used by different projects.

As "IDE" I'm using RStudio.

Is it possible somehow to define the path to R on the startup of RStudio automatically?

I know that its possible to select [manually](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R) the R-Version. But I would like to have it automatically.

Are there some command line options for RStudio? (So I could just set value for Shortcut.)

Or is there some place where RStudio stores the path to R? (So I could write a script which modifies the path before starting RStudio.) In the support they write about the [location of settings](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-s-State). But I wasn't able to find the path to R there.

**Edit:** The OS is Windows

Comment: You are not providing your OS.

Comment: Windows (and currently optional: Linux)

Comment: Did you ask to RStudio support?

Comment: on OS X I can set the `RSTUDIO_WHICH_R`. I (thankfully) have no idea if this works on Windows. Here's the link to RStudio support (where you will probably get a good reply): https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us